.NET Core Radio Button Binding to Bool
I have a radio button to select which of these 'ShipViaDetails' is default (IsDefault)
public class ShipViaDetails
{
    public string ShipCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool HasAccess { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
}

When I submit to my controller the IsDefault is not being set correctly:
<td>
    <input type="radio"
           name="IsDefault"
           value="@svias.ShipViaAccesses[i].ShipCode"
    @(svias.ShipViaAccesses[i].IsDefault ? "checked" : "")
           hx-post="@url"
           hx-trigger="change"
           hx-target="this" />
</td>

How am I correctly supposed to create this radio button?

Can you show your controller action on how it receive the request body? Are you sending an object or array?

You need a list to correctly bind the properties to the model instance, your html looks like you do initialized a data list. Since you provided no controller code, here is a sample for you to refer to.
ShipViaDetailsController.cs
public class ShipViaDetailsController : Controller
{
    private static List<ShipViaDetails> ShipViaAccesses = new List<ShipViaDetails>
    {
        new ShipViaDetails { ShipCode = "101", HasAccess = true, IsDefault = false },
        new ShipViaDetails { ShipCode = "102", HasAccess = true, IsDefault = true },
        new ShipViaDetails { ShipCode = "103", HasAccess = false, IsDefault = false }
    };

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(ShipViaAccesses);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SetDefault(string selectedShip)
    {
        foreach (var ship in ShipViaAccesses)
        {
            ship.IsDefault = ship.ShipCode == selectedShip;
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}

}
Index.cshtml
<form asp-action="SetDefault" method="post">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ShipCode</th>
                <th>Default</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < svias.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@svias[i].ShipCode</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio"
                               name="SelectedShip" 
                               value="@svias[i].ShipCode" 
                               @(svias[i].IsDefault ? "checked" : "") 
                        />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Save Default</button>
</form>


